# How to show a specific version of a sharepoint publishing page instead of the most current approved version to anonymous users

Tags: sharepoint, versioning, publishing-site

I am trying to create a control that will deliver any specific version of a sharepoint publishing page to anonymous users. Example:

MyPage.aspx has versions 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, with 4.0 being the latest published verison. Sharepoint by default will deliver version 4.0 to anonymous users. I want to be able to programmatically give them version 2.0 instead. I know how to check for anonymous users, and get the object for the version of the page that I want. My question is, how do i tell sharepoint to deliver the specified page object?

Below is what I am working with so far...

```
PublishingPage currentPage = GetCurrentPageObjectVersion(2);
        if (currentPage != null)
        {
            // Tell sharepoint to deliver currentPage somehow?
        }

private SPFileVersion GetCurrentPageObjectVersion(int requestedVersion)
    {
        SPFileVersion specifiedVersion = null;
        try
        {
            PublishingPage currentPage = PublishingPage.GetPublishingPage(SPContext.Current.ListItem);
            specifiedVersion = currentPage.ListItem.File.Versions.GetVersionFromID(requestedVersion);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Error handling here
        }

        return specifiedVersion;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated! Please let me know if any further clarification is needed!

Comment: have you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your SPFileVersion, you can get the list item associated with the specific version of the page. Your control can then set (override) the values of the field controls on the page (defined by the page's page layout) with the versioned list item's property values.

Comment: You will also need to run the code with elevated privileges since anonymous users are not allowed to view versions.